# Bootstrap Navbar CSS unwanted effect

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm kind of new to CSS, so please excuse me if I can't describe this problem properly. It happens on Chrome and Safari, but not FireFox. The blue rectangle appears when I click on a navigation menu tab. I don't know what is it related, so I don't know how to get rid of it. Any help will much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: set focus  to 0 for that nav

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: posting it as answer

Comment: Consider that perhaps Chrome and Safari have good reason for this effect http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link:focus {
  outline:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Safari by default keep the focus on the last clicked element, and hence the blue outline appears..

You might have to add `outline:none` to the `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-class to the element you want to avoid this outline.